# how to add average rasters within for-loop that creates the rasters? R

Tags: r, for-loop, raster, r-raster

I have several directories with 700+ binary encoded rasters that i take average the output rasters per directory. however, i currently create the rasters 1 by 1 in a for loop, then load newly created rasters back into R to take the sum to obtain the monthly rainfall total.

However, since I dont need the individual rasters, only the average raster, I have a hunch that I could do this all w/in 1 loop and not save the rasters but just the output average raster, but I am coming up short in how to program this in R.

```
setwd("~/Desktop/CMORPH/Levant-Clip/200001")

dir.output <- '~/Desktop/CMORPH/Levant-Clip/200001' ### change as needed to give output location
path <- list.files("~/Desktop/CMORPH/MonthlyCMORPH/200001",pattern="*.bz2", full.names=T, recursive=T)

for (i in 1:length(path)) {
  files = bzfile(path[i], "rb")
  data <- readBin(files,what="double",endian = "little", n = 4948*1649, size=4) #Mode of the vector to be read
  data[data == -999] <- NA #covert missing data from -999(CMORPH notation) to NAs
  y<-matrix((data=data), ncol=1649, nrow=4948)
  r <- raster(y)
  e <- extent(-180, 180, -90, 83.6236) ### choose the extent based on the netcdf file info 
  tr <- t(r) #transpose 
  re <- setExtent(tr,extent(e)) ### set the extent to the raster
  ry <- flip(re, direction = 'y')
  projection(ry) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84"
  C_Lev <- crop(ry, Levant) ### Clip to Levant
  M_C_Lev<-mask(C_Lev, Levant)
  writeRaster(M_C_Lev, paste(dir.output, basename(path[i]), sep = ''), format = 'GTiff', overwrite = T) ###the basename allows the file to be named the same as the original
}
# 
raspath <- list.files ('~/Desktop/CMORPH/Levant-Clip/200001',pattern="*.tif",     full.names=T, recursive=T)
rasstk <- stack(raspath)
sum200001<-sum(rasstk)
writeRaster(avg200001, paste(dir.output, basename(path[i]), sep = ''), format = 'GTiff', overwrite = T) ###the basename allows the file to be named the same as the original
```

currently, this code takes about 75 mins to execute, and I have about 120 more directories to go, and am looking for faster solutions.

thank you for all and any comments and input. best, evan

Comment: It seems to me that writing the rasters should not be reallt needed,  since stack accepts also a list of raster objects in input.  So,  you could just substitute writeraster with sequentially assigning M_C_lev to elements of a list.  This could be memory hungry,  however.  Alsi,  if you are sure all rastet have rhe same extent,  consider using the 'quick'  optiin in stack.

Comment: Also, i seem to recall that 'brick'  could be faster than 'stack'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my previous comment, you could try:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/CMORPH/Levant-Clip/200001")

dir.output <- '~/Desktop/CMORPH/Levant-Clip/200001' ### change as needed to give output location
path <- list.files("~/Desktop/CMORPH/MonthlyCMORPH/200001",pattern="*.bz2", full.names=T, recursive=T)
raster_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(path)) {
  files = bzfile(path[i], "rb")
  data <- readBin(files,what="double",endian = "little", n = 4948*1649, size=4) #Mode of the vector to be read
  data[data == -999] <- NA #covert missing data from -999(CMORPH notation) to NAs
  y<-matrix((data=data), ncol=1649, nrow=4948)
  r <- raster(y)
  if (i == 1) {
    e <- extent(-180, 180, -90, 83.6236) ### choose the extent based on the netcdf file info 

  }
  tr <- t(r) #transpose 
  re <- setExtent(tr,extent(e)) ### set the extent to the raster
  ry <- flip(re, direction = 'y')
  projection(ry) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84"
  C_Lev <- crop(ry, Levant) ### Clip to Levant
  M_C_Lev<-mask(C_Lev, Levant)
  raster_list[[i]] = M_C_Lev
}
# 

rasstk <- stack(raster_list, quick = TRUE) # OR rasstk <- brick(raster_list, quick = TRUE)
avg200001<-mean(rasstk)
writeRaster(avg200001, paste(dir.output, basename(path[i]), sep = ''), format = 'GTiff', overwrite = T) ###the basename allows the file to be named the same as the original
```

Using the "quick" options in `stack` should definitely speed-up things, in particular if you have many rasters.

Another possibility is to first compute the average, and then perform the "spatial proceesing". For example:

```
for (i in 1:length(path)) {
  files = bzfile(path[i], "rb")
  data <- readBin(files,what="double",endian = "little", n = 4948*1649, size=4) #Mode of the vector to be read
  data[data == -999] <- NA #covert missing data from -999(CMORPH notation) to NAs

  if (i == 1) {
   totdata  <-  data 
   num_nonNA <- as.numeric(!is.na(data))
  } else {
totdata = rowSums(cbind(totdata,data), na.rm = TRUE)
# We have to count the number of "valid" entries so that the average is correct !
num_nonNA = rowSums(cbind(num_nonNA,as.numeric(!is.na(data))),na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}

avg_data = totdata/num_nonNA # Compute the average

# Now do the "spatial" processing

y<-matrix(avg_data, ncol=1649, nrow=4948)
r <- raster(y)
e <- extent(-180, 180, -90, 83.6236) ### choose the extent based on the netcdf file info 
tr <- t(r) #transpose 
re <- setExtent(tr,extent(e)) ### set the extent to the raster
ry <- flip(re, direction = 'y')
projection(ry) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84"
C_Lev <- crop(avg_data, Levant) ### Clip to Levant
M_C_Lev<-mask(C_Lev, Levant)
writeRaster(M_C_Lev, paste(dir.output, basename(path[i]), sep = ''), format = 'GTiff', overwrite = T) ###the basename allows the file to be named the same as the original
```

This could be faster or slower, depending from "how much" you are cropping the original data.

HTH,

Lorenzo

Comment: Lorenzo, thank you for the answer, the code is still running and i will reply with time results. the flipping and transposing is unfortunately necessary and part of the way the CMOPRH precip data coded in binary that way. I am going to try to just flip and transpose after the loop though once it is stacked.

Comment: glad to help. Transposing and flipping only the mean image seems a good idea, but I don't know if it will cope well with `crop` and `mask`. I also recon that if you get into memory problems you could try doing a different thing: cumulating the values within the for loop, and then computing the average outside the loop. In that way, you'll just have two "items" in memory : The current cumulate and the "current" single date file...

Comment: Added to the reply a possibly faster approach. Have a look.

Comment: So, after much comparisons, I have not been able to improve much in time. Lorenzo, your second approach threw a "Error: cannot allocate vector of size n Mb" after an hour or so. I am now going back and using the "foreach" and "doParellel" libraries to speed things up.

Comment: Hi Even. Two quick things: 1) I updated the code of the second method because I saw that using "rowSums" instead than apply gratly reduces time. I tried the code making a 700-iterations cycle and creating each time a 4948*1649 array, and it took less than 5 minutes to complete the cycle. Maybe you want to try it out.

Comment: 2) I just noticed that you are reading in compressed files. Could it be that your true bottleneck is in file reading time ? I'd try to see where your scrip gets stuck using profiling [See HERE](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio#using-the-profiler)

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I just realized that in the OP i wrote mean, but i am actually interested in the SUM instead. Does that mean I can omit the totdata and non_numNA lines of your suggestion?

Comment: If you need only the sum, you can remove the `num_nonNA <- as.numeric(!is.na(data))` and `num_nonNA = rowSums(cbind(num_nonNA,as.numeric(!is.na(datain))),na.rm = TRUE)` lines, as well as the `avg_data = totdata/num_nonN` lines. The "totdata" lines need to stay there: they are the ones computing the sum. In practice, at the first cycle you put the first file in "totdata", at the second you sum it to the second file, at the third you sum the previous sum to the second file, etcetera. This allows to only load one array at a time thus preserving memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125022/discussion-between-evan-and-lorenzo-busetto).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer to clarify and simplify things a bit, also in relation with comments in chat. The code below should do what you ask: that is, cycle over files, read the "data", compute the sum over all files and convert it to a raster with specified dimensions.

***Note that for testing purposes here I substituted your cycle on file names with a simple 1 to 720 cycle, and file reading with the creation of arrays of the same length as yours filled with values from 1 to 4 and some NA !***

```
totdata <- array(dim = 4948*1649)  # Define Dummy array
for (i in 1:720) {
  message("Working on file: ", i)
  data <- array(rep(c(1,2,3,4),4948*1649/4), dim = 4948*1649) # Create a "fake" 4948*1649 array  each time to simulate data reading
  data[1:1000] <- -999   # Set some values to NA
  data[data == -999] <- NA #convert missing data from -999

  totdata <- rowSums(cbind(totdata, data), na.rm = T)   # Let's sum the current array with the cumulative sum so far
}

# Now reshape to matrix and convertt to raster, etc.
y  <- matrix(totdata, ncol=1649, nrow=4948)
r  <- raster(y)
e  <- extent(-180, 180, -90, 83.6236) ### choose the extent based on the netcdf file info
tr <- t(r) #transpose
re <- setExtent(tr,e) ### set the extent to the raster
ry <- flip(re, direction = 'y')
projection(ry) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84"
```

This generates a "proper" raster:

```
> ry
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1649, 4948, 8159252  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.07275667, 0.1052902  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 83.6236  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 2880  (min, max)
```

contatining the sum of the different arrays: You can notice that max value is 720 * 4 = 2880 (*Only caveat: If you have cells which are always at NA, you will get 0 instead than NA*)

On my laptop, this runs in about 5 minutes !

In practice:

1. to avoid memory problems, I am not reading in memory all the data.
   Each of your arrays is more or less 64MB, so I cannot load them all
   and then do the sum (unless I have 50 GB of RAM to throw away - and even in
   that case it would be slow). I instead make use of the associative
   propoerty of summation by computing a "cumulative" sum at each
   cycle. In this way you are only working with two 8-millions arrays at
   a time: the one you read from file "i", and the one that contains
   the current sum.
2. to avoid unnecessary computations here I am summing directly the
   1-dimensional arrays I get from reading the binary. You don't need
   to reshape to matrix the arrays in the cycle because you can do that
   on the final "summed" array which you can then convert to matrix form

I hope this will work for you and that I am not missing something obvious !

As far as I can understand, if using this approach is still slow you are having problems elsewhere (for example in data reading: on 720 files, 3 seconds spent on reading for each file means roughly 35 minutes of processing).

HTH,

Lorenzo